# Reset Jquery animated elements. Help please?

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery-animate

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("li.playerContainer").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({paddingBottom:"150px", paddingTop:"150px", paddingRight:"230px", marginTop: "-150px", queue:true});
    $("p").animate({opacity:1},2500);
  });

  $(".go").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().animate({queue:true, paddingBottom:"0", paddingTop:"0", paddingRight:"0", marginTop: "0"});
    $("p").hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

I am trying to use .animate to expand an li element in unordered list. I have successfully expand and close every each of them.  What I need help on is that I want to close the one that already opened when i click another to open, and without close the opened one first. So only one in about ten li element can be opened.

Sorry i am very new to jquery, and i am stuck on this problem.  Please help!!

Comment: What do you mean by "open" here?

Comment: how i code it now is.. when the users click on the "li"  .. the "li" expand it out with padding increase effect. However, they have to click it again to have the padding back to normal before they can click to expand another one, otherwise they will be both expanded and overlap each other.  I want to code it where the users do not have to click the close the "already expanded" one.  but just click another "li" elements, and the "already expanded" one will be close automatically.  I'm sorry, English is my second language, and i'm not really good at it much.  Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Do you want to just reset the other li's to their default state or animate them back to their original size?

Comment: yes... but I have to click the button i created inside that li, what i exactly want that you dont have to click on the button inside the li, but just click to expand the next one, and that one will be reset back to default state.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do, but take a look at this and tell me if that's the effect you're going for: http://jsfiddle.net/xyaAE/

Comment: Thanks you that's exactly how i want.  You are my life saver. Thanks so much

Comment: I have another problem, the set of code you gave me worked like a charm, thanks so much for that.  But now I want to add another button inside the code to click on and load a div in another page.  Unfortunately, every time I click that button, it acted like I just only clicked onto the "li" itself, the button won't work even if I just want to click and get to another site. What can I do to make it clickable by itself.  Thanks

Comment: Looks good. I noticed a couple of what appear to be z-index issues: when the bios scroll up toward the top under the drop shadow for the banner across the top, they go behind the image and are no longer clickable - not sure if this is what you had intended. I also noticed the circle with the x in it on the first bio isn't clickable, but the one in the second one is. The site looks good though and I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't notice your previous comment - I'll take a look at it, but which button, exactly, are you referring to? Is it the historical events button? When I click that it opens up another div, but it's placed behind some other things in the middle and I can't interact with it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and feedback, what can i do with the z-index bug? I try it with css, it does not seem to be working.